# tcp/ip packets get gigantic communication in Citrix environment

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, citrix

Recently we are seeing issues with communication with TCP/IP packets in citrix environment.

The packet is getting size of more that 1GB and it has all empty spaces. The communication is between .net to .net application using TCP/IP. the sender application is published as application from citrix and the receiver application is running on server.

when the sender application is running directly from desktop (not the citrix xen app) then the packets are less than 25Kb and there is no issue with the communication.

Sample code for sending data..

```
private void SendData(byte[] outbound_Message)
    {
        try
        {
            sendArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            sendArgs.SetBuffer(outbound_Message, 0, outbound_Message.Length);
            sendArgs.UserToken = socket;
            socket.SendAsync(sendArgs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UpdateLog(new HDMMessage { Message = MessageHelpers.GetLogMessage(ex, "SendData Failed:") });
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would be glad to provide you more details, But what kind of details you are looking ?

Comment: client code ... what type of packets are sent ... etc

Comment: added code for client side..

Comment: I'd suspect that something supplies the large data blocks ... is that a possibility?

Comment: The data I am passing is very less... less than 25 Kb but on the receiving application it gets more than I gb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57455/discussion-between-nipiv-and-darek).

Comment: Are you reading on the server side properly, handling reads of less than the requested amount?

Comment: There are no packets in TCP visible at the application layer. You're receiving the data incorrectly. Post the receiving code.